# retrieving entire array from MongoDB with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve all documents inside an array, and I want to put all of these in a list in C#.

I have a class called Subject with an list of users, called followers. It's defined like this:

```
public class Subject
{
    public Guid _id { get; set; }
    public List<User> Followers { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm using this function:

```
await db.Subjects.Find( FILTER HERE ).ToListAsync();
```

I just can't seem to get it to work, any help would be appreciated!

Edit: This is my document structure for my subjects

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"/mRuH9AiWEiEJV2Ad0UAVg=="),
    "name" : "Subject test",
    "address" : {
            "Street" : "Street Test",
            "Postalcode" : "1234AB",
            "City" : "City Test",
            "CountryCode" : "NL",
            "Telephone" : "0612345678",
            "Coordinates" : {
                    "Longitude" : "1234",
                    "Latitude" : "1234"
            }
    },
    "Followers" : [
            DBRef("Name test", BinData(3,"uwXp/avTGEeeaR0muzYvOA==")),
            DBRef("Name test", BinData(3,"dK15dIEW302RWg/F1b+rtg=="))
    ],
    "Chefs" : [ ],
    "Owners" : [ ]
}
```

and my user structure:

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"uwXp/avTGEeeaR0muzYvOA=="),
    "name" : "Name test",
    "loginDate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "followers" : [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it throwing an error or is it just empty ?

```
var MySubjets = await db.Subjects.Find( FILTER HERE ).ToListAsync();
```

Has to return an array of subjects matching your filter.

Is that what you want? Or are you looking for the "Followers" array ?

```
var MySubject = await db.Subjects.Find( FILTER HERE ).FirstOrDefault();
foreach (User MyFollower in MySubject.Followers)
{
   //do your stuff...
}
```

But another major thing, is there data in the collection and does the fields correspond to the class properties? When not you have to use [classmappings](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/)

For the DBRefs do something like:

```
var MySubject = await db.Subjects.Find( FILTER HERE ).FirstOrDefault();
foreach (var MyRelatedDocument in MySubject.Followers)
{
    User MyFollower = db.FetchDBRefAs<User>(MyRelatedDocument);
   //do your stuff...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to get all the documents inside that array, I just don't know how to query on it. So where it says 'FILTER HERE' there needs to be a filter which will return me all documents inside that array. Let me know if I'm not clear enough!

Comment: I don't know your classmap, but when you retrieve the subject document the followers array should be filled!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention the array in the document is filled with MongoDBRefs... Sorry I forgot! Do you know how to query on that?

Comment: If you have an array of objectids you can do 2things: lookup in code, or Make an aggregation using the $lookup operator. For an example i need more info About your document structure.

Comment: I added the document structure to the main post

Comment: The first thing i suggest is using ObjectId's instead of Guids. ObjectId's are native and unique to mongo, it gives way better queries. GUID are a pain in the *ss when used in a query / aggregation in something else then C#

Comment: Yeah I wanted to use ObjectIds too, but this was a technical decision made by my team, so I don't have anything to say about it..

Comment: Added some code to the answer, check it out, maybe it's not 100% copy paste, its outta my head ;-)

Comment: That should work, but I'm using an IMongoDatabase, which doesn't give me that function, any ideas?

Comment: Okay update: Thanks to you I got a list with MongoDBRefs in C# now, is there a function where I get a list of users with 1 call to the database? I really don't want to use a for loop, since that might impact the performance negatively when you have multiple followers.

Comment: You could look into the aggregation [$lookup operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Then it's all executed on the database server. but i never use DBRef ([you should rethink useage twice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)).